# What is a patch level in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, patch, ruby-1.9.3, ruby-2.0

I want to know what makes a patch level in Ruby. What is a patch level? Is it just a different version of Ruby that has been released? I understand that https://www.ruby-lang.org gives good notes on the differences between the patches themselves, but I'm still unsure of what a patch level is, and if it's different from a patch.

What is a patch level, compared to a version? Is there a difference between a patch, a patch level and a version? Is there anywhere where these kinds of definitions can easily be looked up? (I have tried googling.)

Thank you.

Comment: Here's [Ruby's announcement of movement toward semantic versioning](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2013/12/21/semantic-versioning-after-2-1-0/) after Ruby 2.1. It still isn't a very definitive explanation, but it is the only official source I am finding too.

Comment: Michael, your first link answers my question perfectly, thank you. I am sorry for having posted a duplicate question.

Comment: Not problem at all. Those of us who have been active here for several years typically have good strategies for searching out answers we would expect to already exist. Linking between questions as duplicates is healthy for the site because it means different search terms will eventually lead to the same authoritative answer.  This one took me a few minutes to dig out, but I figured we must have had it somewhere already.